# TSQL: Case when ... end as '

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with a column named `Access` for each record.  I am new to the case when statements in TSQL. I just need to get another column evaluating the case when statement with a new column name:

Currently :

```
select ID, FName, SName, Access = 
    CASE 
        When Access = 'Admin' then 'X'
        else ''
    end 
    MarkUp,

from tb_Test
```

I need the new column to be named something like `MarkUp`. I tried both with `end as MarkUp` and like the statement above but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "but it doesn't work." mean? Your `CASE` **expression**, `Case` (`Switch`) statements don't exist in T-SQL, appears to have 2 aliases: `Access = ...  Markup`. A column can only have a single alias, not 2.

Comment: SQL Server fundamentally has two ways of giving a column an alias, you can use `alias = <expression>`, or `<expression> AS alias` (`AS` is optional). You are currently using both -- `Access = <expression> AS Markup`, which is not valid. Pick one method only, either `Markup = CASE ....END`, or `CASE ... END AS Alias`.  For what it is worth, I prefer `Alias = <expr>`, for reasons set out [here](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases). Effectively it ensures all column names are aligned, making the output easier to read at a glance.

Comment: Remove the comma before the `FROM`.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing alias styles, use either `SELECT Foo = <expr>` vs `SELECT <expr> AS foo` - but not both.

I also recommend putting complex `CASE` expressions in indented parenthesis to make them easier to visually delineate:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    FName,
    SName,
    (
        CASE Access
            WHEN 'Admin' THEN 'X'
            ELSE ''
        END
    ) AS MarkUp
FROM
    tb_Test
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
select ID, FName, SName, 
    CASE 
        When Access = 'Admin' then 'X'
        else ''
    end as
    MarkUp

from tb_Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like any of the below methods:

**Method 1-**

```
SELECT ID, FName, SName, 
    CASE Access
        WHEN 'Admin' THEN 'X'
        ELSE ''
    END AS MarkUp
FROM tb_Test;
```

**Method 2-**

```
SELECT ID, FName, SName, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Access = 'Admin' THEN 'X'
        ELSE ''
    END AS MarkUp
FROM tb_Test;
```

**Method 3-**
We can also use IIF().

```
SELECT ID, FName, SName, 
    IIF(Access = 'Admin','X','') AS MarkUp
FROM tb_Test;
```